# MonoTouch 6 update

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Today I received notifications about software updates:

- Mac OS X 10.7.5;
- Xcode 4.5;
- MonoDevelop 3.XXXX;
- MonoTouch 6.0.

All product were successful installed, except for MonoTouch 6. It tried to replace files, execute scripts, but then... shows message "operation failed":

[image]

How to determine error reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog explains it:

```
Contact the software manufacturer.
```

You can do this by emailing support@xamarin.com

Comment: Done. Yet please note that Xamarin tech help developer once said me to post any question first to stackoverflow to get fastest response.

Comment: This is true for coding related issues, but for something specifically wrong with the product or license you're better off contacting Xamarin.